# ipython notebook with spark gets error with sparkcontext

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm testing turi with this example on my macbook osx 10.10.5
https://turi.com/learn/gallery/notebooks/spark_and_graphlab_create.html

when getting to this step

```
# Set up the SparkContext object
# this can be 'local' or 'yarn-client' in PySpark
# Remember if using yarn-client then all the paths should be accessible
# by all nodes in the cluster.
sc = SparkContext('local')
```

the following error comes up

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-dc1befb4186c> in <module>()
      3 # Remember if using yarn-client then all the paths should be accessible
      4 # by all nodes in the cluster.
----> 5 sc = SparkContext()

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/context.pyc in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    110         """
    111         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
--> 112         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway)
    113         try:
    114             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/context.pyc in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway)
    243         with SparkContext._lock:
    244             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 245                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
    246                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    247 

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/java_gateway.pyc in launch_gateway()
     92                 callback_socket.close()
     93         if gateway_port is None:
---> 94             raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
     95 
     96         # In Windows, ensure the Java child processes do not linger after Python has exited.

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

quick google search gave no help yet.

here is my .bash_profile

```
# added by Anaconda2 4.1.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/me/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.8/libexec
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/pyspark:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH 
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
```

anyone knows how to fix this error?

thanks

Comment: Is the `SPARK_HOME` path correct? Have you set `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master spark://<host>:<port>"` in your environment variables? This could be the `port` number you are missing

Comment: spark_home is correct, i haven't configured PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS, what should I specify in this case??

Comment: Try this `export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"`

Comment: @KartikKannapur i think that actually worked, can you edit your answer so that I can accept it ?  thanks a lot

Comment: Sure glad to help. Will add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could potentially happen because of two reasons:

1. Environment variable `SPARK_HOME` could be pointing to the wrong path
2. Set `export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"` - This is the configuration you want `PySpark` to start with.